How to specify device to aplay?
Platform: ubuntu on WSL
This is a programming question. This is about aplay which is generally used for development of audio systems. Don't close this question just bc you don't know what aplay is. There are lots of other questions about aplay here. I am so sick of my questions being rejected here. I use this platform all the time to learn, but when I add a question people often freak out that it's not appropriate. I know what I'm doing. This is a programming question.
Trying to learn/understand how to program for ALSA output by playing a wav file via aplay. It works via command:
# aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=wm8524audio ~/wav/taunt.wav

But not via:
# aplay -D hw:3,0 ~/wav/taunt.wav
Playing WAVE '/root/wav/taunt.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 22257 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1387: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
- S24_LE
- S32_LE

I did try using each of the suggested formats with -f, like
# aplay -D hw:3,0 ~/wav/taunt.wav -f S16_LE
Warning: format is changed to U8
Playing WAVE '/root/wav/taunt.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 22257 Hz, Mono
aplay: set_params:1387: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S16_LE
- S24_LE
- S32_LE

No idea what "Warning: format is changed to U8" means. Might be relevant.
FYI:
# aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=btscoaudio
    bt-sco-audio, 30020000.sai-bt-sco-pcm-wb bt-sco-pcm-wb-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=imxspdif
    imx-spdif, S/PDIF PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=wm8524audio
    wm8524-audio, HiFi wm8524-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
# aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: btscoaudio [bt-sco-audio], device 0: 30020000.sai-bt-sco-pcm-wb bt-sco-pcm-wb-0 [30020000.sai-bt-sco-pcm-wb bt-sco-pcm-wb-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: imxspdif [imx-spdif], device 0: S/PDIF PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0 [S/PDIF PCM snd-soc-dummy-dai-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: wm8524audio [wm8524-audio], device 0: HiFi wm8524-hifi-0 [HiFi wm8524-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: wm8524audio [wm8524-audio], device 1: HiFi-ASRC-FE (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

From some research, it seems that using the hw: specifier bypasses the asound config files. Therefore, I guess there's config info in an asound config file that allows my device to play the wav when using id "sysdefault:CARD=wm8524audio", but not "hw:3,0". But, the default config file, /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf is >600 lines of goodness. Can't make heads of tails of it.
How can I find the info in the asound config file that allows it to work? How do I go about figuring out how to specify CLI args so that I can use hw: specifier?

Questions about the CLI for running an existing tool are usually off-topic.  The exception is for tools whose primary purpose is computer programming -- basically compilers, linkers, debuggers, version control.  If it makes sense for anyone who's not a computer programmer to use the same program, it's not a programming tool, even if a programmer can't get through the day without it.  (This includes things like your OS, text editor, file transfer software, virtual machine or container host)  aplay doesn't even meet the bar of "needed for programming", so definitely off-topic on SO.

Thanks. Should include this info the 1st time you reject a question. Annoying to be rejected without a reason that clearly pertains. FWIW "primarily used by programmers" is a grey area. I think aplay is primarily used by programmers. And it's possible that a compiler is run by non-programmer (i.e. devops; heck a mgr might when a dev isn't looking :) ). But I kinda get your distinction. You should continue to hone the distinction and then describe that in your rejection notice. Maybe build tools is what you mean. You'll need to consider whether debug tools qualify. And IDEs.

Well, I'm not one of the ones whose votes closed your question, I only came later and saw that no explanation had been given.  BTW I don't agree that "aplay is primarily used by programmers".  Even though I am a programmer, I never used it to help with programming, only for "some GUI media player (from OS package manager) is having problems, how do I check if my audio hardware and drivers are working even enough to play a simple uncompressed file?"  And given the number of blogs explaining how to do that, I'm pretty sure it's the most common usage.

Also note that we do have a sister site, Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, where questions about Linux configuration files and CLI for common Linux tools are welcomed.

@Ben: Thanks for taking the time. Someone else was being rude. You made up for that with your kindness. ... FWIW SO/SE has become a bit toxic. Some folks seem bent on organizing and controlling input in order to forward some agenda. And maybe it's having good results. But, it is intimidating/annoying/angering users.

There is supposed to be an agenda of "make questions and answers useful to as many people as possible".  Making sure things are correctly tagged and on the right site is part of a larger subgoal of "help people find existing answers so they don't have to re-ask questions that already exist".  Duplicate questions are an inefficient use of time, but even worse are the duplicate answers.  Some problems have tricky answers, and when copies of the question are scattered all over, it's very hard to make sure none of the answers have significant bugs (like undefined behavior or SQL injection).
